# Pagination with multiple join with large table size

Tags: oracle

In oracle 12c while trying to fetch data with doing multiple join and filtering the data, then doing pagination using rownum, the tables first gets joined and filtered and then result set ordered with order by and then data is fetched. so in case of large number of rows all the join operations are very costly. Even though we need just 100 out of 1 million result set still all data need to be prepared. Any idea to improvise this process?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a subset of data you could hint query with `FIRST_ROWS(n)`.

[Improved Response Time with FIRST_ROWS(n) Hint for ORDER BY Queries](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-169F2EB1-5E78-43E2-9FFD-1D9DFE2E1AA2.htm#CCAPP9236)

> You use the FIRST_ROWS(n) hint in cases where you want the first number (n) of rows in the shortest possible time.